# ajax post success function not working

Tags: jquery, ajax

This should be simple. All I want to do is issue an ajax post to get a value from my database, and put that value in an input element. I've looked at just about ever tutorial out there and I just can't get it. It successfully hits my server-side MVC controller function which returns the value I need, but the error function of my ajax post keeps firing rather than my success function. Does anyone have any advice?

```
                            $.ajax({
                                url: "@Url.Action("GetClientGUIDFromID", "Account")",
                                type: "POST",
                                data: { clientId: $('#clientIdToSelectFromDropdown').val() },
                                success: function (data) {
                                    $("#guid_client").val(data);
                                },
                                error: function () {
                                    alert('failed');
                                }

                            })
```

Server side code that handles AJAX call from client side:

```
<HttpPost>  
Function GetClientGUIDFromID(clientId As String) As ActionResult
    Dim clientGuid As String
    Dim sCommands As New SQLCommands(MySQLServerNameSetter.SetServerName)
    clientGuid = sCommands.GetValue("main", "client", "Id", clientId, "guid")
    Return Json(clientGuid, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
End Function
```

Comment: Is your server returning a JSON encoded response? If not success will not execute

Comment: Try downloading Telerik's Fiddler so you can easily see what the response is from your server, the response should be 200 (HTTP Ok) otherwise it will go to the error function of you jQuery Ajax call

Comment: Are you sure your serve side method isn't failing, you are hitting a breakpoint and stepping through in Visual Studio with your debugger, correct?

Comment: By the way you can remove JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet from your server side method, using JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet exposes a JSON hacking security vulenarbility where a hacker can access sensitive data in your JSON response payload. You are doing a POST type call anyways with your $.ajax so no need for JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet. There times that you need JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet in response to a GET but your Ajax call is not one of them.

Comment: Yes sir, I have a break point set on my server function and it's getting my value from the db...is it possible that it's failing because my JS is on my _layout.vbhtml file? I wouldn't think that would matter...I'll remove the JsonRequestBehavior and do some more testing, I didn't have it initially, but figured I'd give it a try (process of elimination)

Comment: No that should not matter, the Ajax call is firing so its location in the Document Object Model is not an issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To figure out the real cause of the problem, open the URL located in @`Url.Action("GetClientGUIDFromID", "Account")` in a separate window. in case of it is POST method try testing it using [POSTMAN](https://www.google.com.sa/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjEy5GM_-3JAhVGc3IKHRc_DAgQFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fchrome.google.com%2Fwebstore%2Fdetail%2Fpostman%2Ffhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop%3Fhl%3Den&usg=AFQjCNE_Yq59TT1ZExzJ68FTldg4ho_lGw&sig2=qR59m3rOw849TxO9x3-AWQ) extension and discover what's the real problem coming to you

Also another way to get the error details about the problemchange the error handler to be like the following

```
$.ajax({
    url: "@Url.Action("GetClientGUIDFromID", "Account")",
    type: "POST",
    data: { clientId: $('#clientIdToSelectFromDropdown').val() },
    success: function (data) {
        $("#guid_client").val(data);
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
        alert(err.Message);
    }

})
```

After addition of server side code give the following trials and update in comments if it's working fine: (according to your Routings, one of the following should work )

```
$.ajax({
    url: "@Url.Action("GetClientGUIDFromID", "Account")",
    type: "POST",
    data: { clientId: $('#clientIdToSelectFromDropdown').val() },
    dataType: "application/json"
    success: function (data) {
        $("#guid_client").val(data);
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
        alert(err.Message);
    }

})
```

Or

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/account/GetClientGUIDFromID/" + $('#clientIdToSelectFromDropdown').val(),
    type: "POST",
    success: function (data) {
        $("#guid_client").val(data);
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
        alert(err.Message);
    }

})
```

Or

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/account/GetClientGUIDFromID/?clientId=" + $('#clientIdToSelectFromDropdown').val(),
    type: "POST",
    success: function (data) {
        $("#guid_client").val(data);
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
        alert(err.Message);
    }

})
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. The good news is, none of these hit the error function. The bad news is, none of them hit the success function. :( I must have something weird going on behind the scenes because this shouldn't be very difficult

Comment: Well this is embarrassing. There's another post function further down that's interfering with the one I'm writing. The first solution you provided is working now that I've commented out the other post function. Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Give a try :

```
$.ajax({

url: "@Url.Action("GetClientGUIDFromID", "Account")",
type: "POST",
data:'clientId='+ $('#clientIdToSelectFromDropdown').val(),
dataType: 'json'
}).done(function(data) {    

//The json is null so probably failed
if(data === null)
  alert('failed');

//Display your json in a console 
console.log(json);  


});
```

Ok since your edit, add -> dataType: 'json' then if it work, the data json will appear in the console (after you may use some of the key as json.key...)